# Loaction icon animations using pure css

Tags: html, css, sass, css-animations

I planned to do like a drop of water travelling around a location icon.Tried a bit,but i couldn't let the water revolve perfectly around the location icon as I'm not much into animation stuffs.

Here is my code,

```
 <div id ="location">
    <div id = "droplet"></div>
 </div>

    #location {
      background: black;
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
      border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
      transform:rotate(-45deg);  
    }

    #location::after{
        content '';
        width 14px;
        height 14px;
        margin: 8px 0 0 8px;
        background: #89849b;
        position absolute;
        border-radius 50%;
    }

    #droplet {
     background: #2c3e50;
     height: 50px;
     width: 50px;
     border-radius:50%;
     border:  5px double darkgreen;
     margin: 23%; 
     -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
     -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
     -webkit-animation-duration:4s 
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes rotate{
      0%{-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) rotateY(0) scale(0)}
      30%{-webkit-transform: rotate(90eg) rotateY(0) scale(0.7)}
      80%{-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) rotateY(0) scale(1)}
      100%{-webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg) rotateY(0) scale(0)}
    }
```

How to make the droplet revolves within the location icon(but it should move around its edges)

Comment: I think this lacks explanation, specially when you are talking about animations you should be really clear about the requirements that you are asking. Revolving around the black icon? Does that means that the blue pulsating animation should move? If it should move how? Around the black location icon on it's borders? Or make it appear randomly anywhere within the location icon? Here is a fiddle by the way:

https://jsfiddle.net/e3c70u19/

Comment: sorry for the lack of explanation.I need the droplet revolves within the black location icon,but it should move around its edges